# Dynamic Filters with Entity Framework 3.5 and Eager Loading

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a db model with the following tables:

**A**  * ---- 1  **B**  1 ---- *  **C**

Based on this schema I have created a Entity Data Model which allows me to load all the As in my DB. As I also use the Bs in my Linq queries I load the As like this:

```
using(MyEntities entities = new MyEntities()){
  var result = from a in entities.As.Include("B") where a.Code == 123 && a.B.Code == 321 select a;
}
```

The results can be further filtered by the user so I am building filters depending on the user's selection like this:

```
int filterValue = 222; //FilterValue is passed in by the user
IList<Func<A, bool>> filters = new List<Func<A, bool>>();
filters.Add(x => x.B.C.Any(i => i.C.Code == filterValue));
...build more filters...
```

Later on I apply the filters using:

```
foreach (var filter in filters)
{
  results = results.Where(filter);
}
```

Notice that in the filter code I'm using C reference (which is a collection of Cs). That's where EF fails because the C collection is empty (has not be loaded). How can I force EF to eagerly load all related properties for an object graph so I can apply my filters or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your C is not loaded is because you are not including it in your query. You must use:

```
entities.As.Include("B.C")
```

But the result is as described by @Eranga - you are transferring all records to your application and filters them in your application memory by linq-to-objects instead of doing filtering by linq-to-entities and transferring only filtered records.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `IList<Func<A, bool>>` as filters. This makes it a LINQ-to-Objects query. Thats why you are complaining `C` collection is empty.

So instead use `IList<Expression<Func<A, bool>>>` as filters.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason. Even before applying the filters the property for Cs is an empty collection even though there are definitely items in the database. So I assume it is an issue with EF not loading the related entities in other tables.

Comment: @b3n check the SQL generated for the query. Then you can figure out where the problem is.